# How can I join two dataframes by index in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have two dataframes `CityDF` and `CityIndexDF`. The `CityIndexDF` is the index of the columns in `CityDF` which I got from another computation. So 1 is Stockholm, 2 is Oslo and 3 is Copenhagen.

```
CityDF <- setNames(data.frame(c("Stockholm", "Oslo", "Copenhagen")),"City")
CityIndexDF <- setNames(data.frame(c("1","2","1","3","2","3","1","2")),"Index")
```

I would like the output to be

```
    Index City
    1     Stockholm
    2     Oslo
    1     Stockholm
    3     Copenhagen
    2     Oslo
    3     Copenhagen
    1     Stockholm
    2     Oslo
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that you're putting quotes around your  numbers so they are strings, but if we convert them `as.numeric()`, we can use them as row indexes:

```
CityIndexDF$City <- CityDF$City[as.numeric(CityIndexDF$Index)]
CityIndexDF
#   Index       City
# 1     1  Stockholm
# 2     2       Oslo
# 3     1  Stockholm
# 4     3 Copenhagen
# 5     2       Oslo
# 6     3 Copenhagen
# 7     1  Stockholm
# 8     2       Oslo
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use your col values as the index itself

```
library(tidyverse)

CityIndexDF %>%
    mutate(city = CityDF[Index,])
```